Рекомендовать удаление запоздалого ответа есть, а первого ответа нет - в очереди проверок
Когда проверяешь "запоздалый ответ", то выходит возможность "рекомедовать удаление"
В "первых ответах" такого пункта нету. Почему? Ответ есть ответ - какая разница первый или запоздалый. По-моему хорошо было бы предложить добавить для удобства, такой же механизм в проверки для первых ответов
кстати на скриншоте видно, что это первый ответ (других ответов нету), но он "запоздалый", тк сам вопрос задан давно



Здесь предлагать изменения функционала сайта бесполезно - всё равно ничего не изменится. Это нужно постить на MSE

@wchistow,вы правы, наверно я делаю заметки? Когда выучу английский должным образом, то предложу там, но тут помечаю, что можно улучшить по мере работе с сайтом. Потом могу забыть?... А может кто согласен со мной и знает английский и есть свободное время, то он запостит "там", мне "тут" удобней теплей и уютней. Я каждый раз думаю, что у меня то появилась кнопка, то пропала..... Вроде и там и там "ответ" , а разные интрейфейсы. (я про "рекомендовать удаление")

@wchistow, Dev18 не просто предлагает изменить, а в первую очередь спрашивает почему так.

@чистов_n,  тоже верно, сбивает с толку. И вопрос возник. Заходишь на проверку "ответа", то есть то нет...---предположу, что наверно там были только "ответы" раньше, потом добавили "запоздалые" и улучшили интерфейс, там наверно по дате проверяют, и если к примеру за год никто не ответил, то считается что это "сложный" вопрос, и ответ должен быть "на уровне", и тут добавили "рекомендовать удаление" даже для тех, у кого рейтинг меньше 3000...что то такое наверно, но это лишь мои предположения, и что бывает вообще, если я "рекомендую удаление", оно наверно в очередь идет? какая разница с тревогой

Особо подробно не исследовал этот нюанс по ответам на MSE. Но как я понял, основной момент в том, что "первые вопросы" и "первые ответы" подразумевают, что сообщение поступило от новичка сайта, который совсем не знаком с правилами SE. Чтобы не отпугнуть такого участника (который может быть полезен, если чуть лучше ознакомится с правилами позднее) вариант "рекомендовать удаление" отсутствует, но есть опции по улучшению поста.
Конечно, может быть ситуация, что опубликована какая-то совсем дичь, но в этом случае надо вешать подходящую тревогу (может быть даже с привлечением модератора), а не ограничиваться доступными опциями в очереди проверок.
Теоретически, запоздалый ответ может быть одновременно и первым ответом, наверное, но даже в этом случае (если такое реально бывает), опции формируются по типу очереди, а не по тому, кто является автором проверяемого сообщения. Поэтому даже несмотря, что запоздалый ответ опубликован новичком и существует концепт "не спугнуть", опция "рекомендовать удаление" всё равно есть - т.к. вытекает из типа очереди (в данном случае, "запоздалые ответы"), куда попало сообщение.

опции формируются по типу очереди, а не по тому, кто является автором проверяемого сообщения => я не понимаю

@Dev18 если цель - не отпугнуть новичка, то его сообщение в очереди "запоздалые ответы" не должно иметь опции "рекомендовать удаление". Но внутри определённой очереди опции всегда одни и те же. Не важно кто автор проверяемого сообщения.


Не важно кто автор проверяемого сообщения => логично, и даже вопроса не возникало(мне больше по датам казалось, то есть прошло время, ...уже считается, что ответ "запоздал"). 2. если цель - не отпугнуть новичка.... => Вы хотите сказать, что разные опции для "запоздалых ответов"? я обращу внимание, интересно


да нет же, на скриншоте же видно, что он новичок => https://i.sstatic.net/LfsRZ7dr.png и опция есть, так что там другой алгоритм

@Dev18 добавил разъяснение в ответ по этому моменту.
